# How to add title with <H1> tag in iText7 pdfHtml without <p> tag inside <H1>

Tags: c#, itext7

I created the HTMl file with  the  tags and generated the pdf using pdfHTML add-on in iText7,C#. But when I checked the pdf accessibility using PAC tool, it returns warning saying, "**Possibly inappropriate use of P Structure element**". `H1` tag is applied to pdf with the `<p>` tag. It means`,<p>` tag is in inside the `<h1>` tag. How can I add title using H1 tag without PAC tool errors?
Thanks.

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

C# code:

```
IList<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(htmlString,converterProperties);
foreach(IElement element in elements){
doc.Add((IBlockElement)element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't use the html tag but do it like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
         <h1>Title</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I tried out removing <html> tag. No luck. Still get the same things

Comment: Can you link your c#, perhabs your problem lays there

Comment: Thanks. Your htmlString where do you add your html file in that?

Comment: Read the html file and get the content to the "htmlString".

Comment: Okey check this post: https://taggedpdf.com/508-pdf-help-center/possibly-inappropriate-use-of-a-structure-element/